# Vuetify grid layout v-layout v-flex

Tags: vue.js, grid, responsive, vuetify.js

I want the textbox to be 6 column on screen greater than sm and 12 column for mobile.

I use the vuetify grid but it does not work as expected.

this is my code:

```
<v-card-text>
        <v-layout   warp>
          <v-flex xs12 sm6  class="pa-1">
            <v-text-field
              ref="name"
              v-model="password.name"
              label="Name"
              solo
              placeholder="Full Name"
              counter="25"
            ></v-text-field>
          </v-flex>
          <v-flex xs12 sm6  class="pa-1">
            <v-combobox
              v-model="password.keys"
              label="Add keys"
              chips
              solo
              multiple
            >
              <template slot="selection" slot-scope="data">
                <v-chip :selected="data.selected" close @input="remove(data.item)">
                  <strong>{{ data.item}}</strong>&nbsp;
                </v-chip>
              </template>
            </v-combobox>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
```

In the mobile view, the elements are in the same row.

What can be the reason, and how can I fix it?

This is the mobile version:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo on the "v-layout" should be wrap not warp.

https://codesandbox.io/s/my49o8vo9y

Comment: The code does not work anymore..

Answer (score 2):

For new comers looking why `v-layout` & `v-flex` don't work anymore in `Vuetify 3`: it looks like those have been removed and are no longer working. Please use `v-row` & `v-col` respectively.

Comment: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids/#v-container